Quiero registrar datos de Información del empleado usando el api de google pero sin tener que crear custom schemas
Quiero registrar datos de Información del empleado usando el api de google pero sin tener que crear custom schemas.
Con api y php logre crear usuarios mas nos puedo registrar datos en los campos:
Work Address, Employee ID, Employee Type,Department
enter image description here
Quiero llenar estos campos
enter image description here
Comparto mi código:
<?php
$autoloadPath = ruta del autoload.php
$keyFilePath = ruta del json
        // Verificación de la ruta
        if (!file_exists($autoloadPath)) {
            throw new Exception("No se puede encontrar autoload.php en la ruta: " . $autoloadPath);
        }
        require_once $autoloadPath;

        // Scopes necesarios para la API
        $scopes = [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security"
        ];

        // Configuración del cliente de servicio
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig($keyFilePath);
        $client->setScopes($scopes);

        // Delegación en nombre de un superadministrador
        $client->setSubject('superadmin account'); // Reemplaza con el correo del superadmin

        // Obtener el token de acceso
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
        $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

        $apellidos = 'ALCAZAR ALBA';
        $nombres = 'YA VOY';
        $nombres_apellidos = 'YA VOY ALCAZAR ALBA';
        $email = 'ya.alcazar@gmail.com';
        $email_empresa = 'correo dominio empresa';
        $emailempresa_password = 'Pandora19@5';
        $unidad_organizativa = 'Ruta Unidad';
        $codper = '00000001';
        // Datos del nuevo usuario
        $data = [
            'name' => [
                'familyName' => ucwords($apellidos),
                'givenName' => ucwords($nombres),
                'displayName' => ucwords($nombres_apellidos)
            ],
            'password' => $emailupch_password,
            'primaryEmail' => strtolower($email_empresa),
            'orgUnitPath' => $unidad_organizativa,
            'recoveryEmail' => $email,
            'changePasswordAtNextLogin' => true,
            'customSchemas' => [
            'EmployeeInfo' => [
            'EmployeeID' => '71313938'
                ]
            ],
            'Employee ID' => $codper,
            'Departamento' => 'OUTI'
            
        ];
          
        // Convertir los datos a JSON
        $jsonData = json_encode($data);

        // Configurar cURL para la solicitud POST
        $url = 'https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Enviar la solicitud y manejar la respuesta
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error en la solicitud: ' . curl_error($ch);
        } else {
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($httpCode == 200 || $httpCode == 201) {
                echo "Usuario creado exitosamente: " . json_encode(json_decode($response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            } else {
                echo "Error en la solicitud: HTTP $httpCode\n";
                echo "Contenido del error: " . json_encode(json_decode($response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            }
        }

        curl_close($ch);

  

    ?>  

Como pueden observar uso el api de google para generar las cuentas y lo estoy generando pero solo genera custom schemas siempre y cuando he creado el esquema pero la información del empleado ya existe y es la que quiero registrar pero la mayoria de recomendaciones sugieren custom schemas quisiera saber que campos son Work Address, Employee ID, Employee Type,Department o como los podria registrar.
